# Calculation of the removal percentage for chemical parameters (faster code)

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have to calculate the removal pecentages of chemical/biological parameters (e.g. after an oxidation process) in a waster water treatment plant.
My code code works so far and does exactly what it should do, but it is really slow.
On my laptop the calculation for the original dataset took about 10 sec and on my PC 4 sec for a 15x80 Data Frame. That is too long, especially if I have to deal with more rows.

**What the code does**:
The formula for the single removal is defined as: 1 - n(i)/n(i-1)
and for the total removal: 1 - n(i)/n(0)

Every measuring point has its own ID. The code searches for the ID's and performs the calculation and saves it in the data frame.

Here is an example (I cant post the original data):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"ID": ["X1_P0001", "X2_P0001", "X3_P0001", "X1_P0002", "X2_P0002", "X3_P0002", "X4_P0002","X5_P0002", "X1_P0003", "X2_P0003", "X3_P0003"],
    "Measurement": [100, 80, 60, 120,90,70,50,25, 85,65,35]}

df["S_removal"]= np.nan
df["T_removal"]= np.nan
```

[Data Frame before calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhCYm.png)

this is my function for the calculation:

```
def removal_TEST(Rem1, Measure, Rem2):
lst = [i.split("_")[1] for i in df["ID"]] #takes relevant ID information
y = np.unique(lst) #stores unique ID values to loop over them
for ID in y: 

    id_list = []                           
    for i in range(0, len(df["ID"])):
        if ID in df["ID"][i]:
            id_list.append(i)
        else:                        # this stores only the relevant id in a new list 
            id_list.append(np.nan)

    indexlist = pd.Series(id_list)           
    first_index = indexlist.first_valid_index() #gets the first and last index of the id list
    last_index = indexlist.last_valid_index()  
    
    col_indizes = []

    for i in range(first_index, last_index+1):
        col_indizes.append(i)
   
    for i in col_indizes:
        if i == 0:                            
            continue      # for i=0 there is no 0-1 element, so i=0 should be skipped
               
        else: 
            Rem1[i]= 1-(Measure[i]/Measure[i-1])
            
    Rem1[first_index]= np.nan      #first entry of an ID must be NaN value



    for i in range(first_index, last_index+1):
        col_indizes.append(i)

    for i in range(len(Rem2)):
        for i in col_indizes:
            Rem2[i]= 1-(Measure[i]/Measure[first_index])

    Rem2[first_index]= np.nan
```

this is the result:
[Final Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqf20.png)

I am new to Python and to stackoverflow (so sorry if my code and question are not so good to read). Are there any good libraries to speed up my code, or do you have some suggestions?

Thank you :)

Comment: what do you mean by "15x80 Data Frame"?

Comment: 15 rows and 80 columns. For each paramater I have to create a new column for its single and total removal

Comment: so you'd have 80 `Measurement` columns and you'd end up with 160 outputs? in that case it might be worth changing the solution to take advantage of that structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of Pandas seems to be getting in the way of solving the problem.  The only relevant state seems to be when the group changes and the first and previous measurement values for each row.

I'd be tempted to solve this just using Python primitives, but you could solve this in other ways if you had lots of data (i.e. millions of rows).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": ["X1_P0001", "X2_P0001", "X3_P0001", "X1_P0002", "X2_P0002", "X3_P0002", "X4_P0002","X5_P0002", "X1_P0003", "X2_P0003", "X3_P0003"],
    "Measurement": [100, 80, 60, 120,90,70,50,25, 85,65,35],
    "S_removal": float('nan'),
    "T_removal": float('nan'), 
})

# somewhere keep track of the last group identifier
last = None

# iterate over rows
for idx, ID, meas in zip(df.index, df['ID'], df['Measurement']):
    # what's the current group name
    _, grp = ID.split('_', 1)
    # see if we're in a new group
    if grp != last:
        last = grp
        # track the group's measurement
        grp_meas = meas
    else:
        # calculate things
        df.loc[idx, 'S_removal'] = 1 - meas / last_meas
        df.loc[idx, 'T_removal'] = 1 - meas / grp_meas
    # keep track of the last measurement
    last_meas = meas
```

I've commented the code in the hopes it makes sense.  This takes ~2 seconds for 1000 copies of your example data, so 11000 rows.

Given that OP has said this needs to be done for a wide dataset, here's another version that reduces runtime to ~30ms for 11000 rows and 2 columns:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "ID": ["X1_P0001", "X2_P0001", "X3_P0001", "X1_P0002", "X2_P0002", "X3_P0002", "X4_P0002","X5_P0002", "X1_P0003", "X2_P0003", "X3_P0003"],
    "M1": [100, 80, 60, 120,90,70,50,25, 85,65,35],
    "M2": [100, 80, 60, 120,90,70,50,25, 85,65,35],
}

# reset_index() because code below assumes they are unique
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data)]*1000).reset_index()

# column names
measurement_col_names = ['M1', 'M2']
single_output_names = ['S1', 'S2']
total_output_names = ['T1', 'T2']

# somewhere keep track of the last group identifier
last = None

# somewhere to store intermediate state
vals_idx = []
meas_vals = []
last_vals = []
grp_vals = []

# iterate over rows
for idx, ID, meas in zip(df.index, df['ID'], df.loc[:,measurement_col_names].values):
    # what's the current group name
    _, grp = ID.split('_', 1)
    # we're in a new group
    if grp != last:
        last = grp
        # track the group's measurement
        grp_meas = meas
    else:
        # track values and which rows they apply to
        vals_idx.append(idx)
        meas_vals.append(meas)
        last_vals.append(last_meas)
        grp_vals.append(grp_meas)
    # keep track of the last measurement
    last_meas = meas

# convert to numpy array so it vectorises nicely
meas_vals = np.array(meas_vals)

# perform calculation using fast numpy operations
df.loc[vals_idx, single_output_names] = 1 - (meas_vals / last_vals)
df.loc[vals_idx, total_output_names] = 1 - (meas_vals / grp_vals)
```

Comment: I will try your suggestion as sson as I am able to  and will give back feedback. thank you